# Unexpected token in build output

Tags: docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

I'm new to Travis and getting this error in the build output:

```
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml

$ export DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=1.23.1

0.01s$ source ~/virtualenv/python3.6/bin/activate

$ python --version

Python 3.6.3

$ pip --version

pip 9.0.1 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
before_install.1

0.01s$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
before_install.2

0.13s$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-'uname -s'-'uname -m' > docker-compose
before_install.3

0.00s$ chmod +x docker-compose
before_install.4

0.01s$ sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin
install

10.72s$ pip install -r requirements.txt

0.02s$ docker-compose up -d --build

/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

This is strange because there is `<` nowhere in my `docker-compose` files. Why am I seeing this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from your `docker-compose.yml` project file but from from the `docker-compose` file itself, which has not been properly downloaded; namely it is not a binary, but a HTML file (hence the `<` character you got):

```
$ export DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=1.24.1
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download\
  /${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-'uname -s'-'uname -m' > docker-compose

$ file docker-compose
docker-compose: HTML document, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

$ head docker-compose
<!DOCTYPE html><title>Malformed request</title>
<body>We didn't receive a proper request from your browser. Please contact us if the problem persists.</body>
</html>
```

To solve this, you should fix your script by using the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) `$(uname -s)`, instead of `'uname -s'`:

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download\
  /${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) > docker-compose

$ file docker-compose
docker-compose: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (...)
```